# Long lasting, reliable Smartphone, 350€ max

Tags: smartphones, android

I am looking for a new Android smartphone.
I currently have the Huawei Honor 8.

I use my phone primarily for the following things:

- Phone Calls
- WhatsApp
- "Gaming"
- Playing music, via headphones or Bluetooth
- Navigation
- Web Browsing
- A few other Apps

Gaming is in quotation marks because I play a lot on the phone, but no high end 3d games, more casual games and such things. That means I don't need peak graphic performance, but a good, long lasting battery.

I have some requirements:

- Long lasting battery
- headphone jack
- Fingerprint sensor
- USB Type-C with fast Charge
- MicroSD slot
- good display
- big screen, 6"+
- decent memory (32GB)
- Good LTE and WiFi connection
- As less bloatware as possible
- Not Huawei...

I have my phone connected to my car via Bluetooth for playing music via Spotify. The Huawei has a lot of problems keeping the connection, seems to be a common problem with that phone, so I guess a stable Bluetooth connection is also a requirement...
Material is not a big concern, but it would be nice if it doesn't break the first time I drop it =)

I don't really care about cameras or dualSim or other fancy stuff.
Speaker doesn't have to be top notch, I only use it for phone calls or for my alarm.

My budget is 350€ (I'm from Germany if that matters...)

I found the Samsung Galaxy A50 or A70, they look promising.
I also read a lot of good things about Xiaomi, but I don't really know the brand...

What would you recommend?

Comment: In terms of price, you may consider buying second-hand. Two benefits: (1) you get a better model for the same money, and (2) you can know how reliable it is based on the actual experience of all the persons who have used it for several years. Personally, I did exactly that four years ago (an HTC from 2013), and it's still working pretty well after being dropped multiple times, and the battery lasts long enough (although this exact model is not an option for you, because of the mismatch with several of your requirements, especially the screen size and the lack of bloatware).

Comment: With a used model you never know how well the battery still is. To be honest, not really an option for me.

Answer (score 2):

I bought a Xiaomi for my Dad last year. Having played with his for a while, I was blown away by how much phone you get for your money.

My vote would be for the [Xiaomi Redmi Note 7](https://www.trustedreviews.com/reviews/xiaomi-redmi-note-7).

From the review on that site, the pros for this phone are:

- Impressive performance
- Long-lasting battery
- Great screen

**Off to a good start!**

It comes with a fingerprint reader, dual sim (which one can be used for a microsd, filling that requirement), headphone jack, 6,3" HD screen, 64GB storage, and USB connection.

All that for [£179/200€ on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Xiaomi-Redmi-Note-Snapdragon-4000mAh/dp/B07PM21BDM)

Answer (score 0):

**Redmi K20 Pro would be the best option in your budget right now.**

You can see the main specifications below

`Processor: Snapdragon 855`

`Ram: 6-8GB`

`Storage: 64-128GB`

`3.5mm Headphone Jack: Available`

`Battery: 4000 MAh`

`Display: No Notch(Full display) running trend with 1080p Amoled panel`

**Summary: This phone is very much reliable as it's build quality, stylish as it's following latest trends. Performance of the phone is high end.**

Answer (score 0):

I have used the A50 for a few weeks, later switching over to the Mi A3.

The Xiaomi is a good phone, with good battery. The fingerprint sensor on the A3 is much more responsive that on the A50, with Samsung having a history of botched under-display sensor firmwares. Also the A50 has some issues with BT connections (can't speak for the A3) when the screen is off.

Personally I would not buy a Chinese phone with a system different than Android One. Aside from potential security considerations, from practical perspective Chinese ROMs are known to aggressively kill background apps.